# Loading modules in the same Python package

Tags: python, python-import

I have a directory structure like this:

```
myPackage /
    __init__.py
    module1
    module2
    module3
    ...
```

Some of these modules depend on other modules in the package. For some reason, I find that importing from e.g. `module1` in `module2` does not work if I write it like this:

```
from module1 import func1, func2, ...
```

This says that there is no module named `module1`, I can' figure out why... Is this not supposed to work? Are there any known pitfalls that could cause this problem? And is there a different approach to load modules in the same package that is preferred?

Comment: where is your script?

Comment: @lxop Sorry, the title with the script part in it was a mistake, I have edited it out.

Comment: OK, similar question then: what is the working directory from which you run the application?

Comment: @lxop Some Jupyter notebook in a completely different folder, but I have added the parent folder of the package to sys.path

Comment: so does your path contain the full path to `myPackage` or its parent?

Comment: @lxop Its parent, so that I can load the modules like this: `myPackage.module1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd like to explain a little bit more.

Every python program has one and only one global hierarchical module management. The modules in `sys.path` are the top modules. So take your code as example:

```
root
----myPackage
--------module1 <- this is what you want.
--------module2
----module1 <- this does not exist.
```

Although you load `module1` in `module2`, it still need to obey current module management which starts outside the package.

This design is used to ensure singleton on modules. All imported modules are cached in `sys.modules`, so to uniquely identify one module, all modules are managed based on hierarchy.

Another example:

In module2:

```
from myPackage import module1
```

And in your main file:

```
from myPackage import module2
import sys
print(sys.modules)
```

You will see one module named `myPackage.module1`, although it is imported in `myPackage.module2`, but it isn't named as `myPackage.module2.myPackage.module1`.

Answer (score 2):

`module1` isn't on your path, so `from module1 import xyz` will not work (because `module1` can't be found).

You can either update the imports to

```
from myPackage.module1 import xyz
```

or

```
from .module1 import xyz
```

The second one is nice in that it avoids duplicating the package name inside the package, but it will mean that you can't easily execute your `module1` directly (e.g. `python module1.py`). If you don't need to execute it directly, then no problem.

Comment: This works. I was under the impression that just `module1` would be enough inside the package, but as you pointed out there is a problem with the path...